# Spraying Drylok Paint?

Tags: painting, spraypainting, sealant

I need to seal my basement walls.

The manufacturer indicates that Drylok can be sprayed. However most professionals I speak with state that it will destroy the gun.

Is it possible to spray Drylok or another sealant paint?

Comment: From what I have heard the extra grit / thickness of the paint destroys the pump. I have no idea if this is true. Drylok states that their sealant / primer can be sprayed. The rental agencies I have spoken to refuse to let me rent the gun if I plan to use Drylok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be sprayed, and says so on the bucket. The spray tip orifice needs to be large though, because drylock is more like pudding.  At least .025" which is bigger than the usual size used for latex paint.